# Data structure for custom indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am looking to write a data structure to represent some genetic data. This data can be represented as a list of size `n`, where each entry also has a "genetic position" which is a real number between 0 and 1. To make nomenclature clear, I'll call the position in the list `id` and the genetic position `gpos`. The way I implemented this is as a class with

```
class Coords(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f = list(*args, **kwargs)
        self.r = dict()
        for i,e in enumerate(self.f):
            self.r[e] = i

    def __setitem__(self,x,y):
        self.f.__setitem__(x,y)
        self.r.__setitem__(y,x)

    def __getitem__(self,x):
        return self.f.__getitem__(x)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.f.__len__()
```

now, I have two issues with this. The first one is that the indeces of self.r are floats, which is obviously a bad idea. I was thinking of converting them to strings (with a fixed number of digits), but is there a better idea? The other issue I have is that I want to implement accessing entries via `gpos`, so if I, for example, would like to access everything between `gpos` 0.2 and 0.4, I would like to be able to do that using

```
import numpy as np
Coords(np.arange(1,0,-.1))
c.r[0.2:0.4]
```

is there an easy way to define that? I was thinking of finding the correct `id` of the starting and ending positions using binary search and then access `self.f` using these ids, but is there a way to implement above syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you index an object with a slice, Python creates a `slice` object with the inputs you provide. For example, if you do `c[0.2:0.4]`, then the argument passed to `c.__getitem__` will be `slice(0.2, 0.4)`. So you could have something like this code in your `__getitem__` method:

```
def __getitem__(self, x):
    if isinstance(x, slice):
        start = x.start
        stop = x.stop
        step = x.step
        # Do whatever you want to do to define your return
    ...
```

If you want to use this fancy indexing not on the `Coords` object, but in the `self.r` dictionary, I think the easiest would be to create a `FancyIndexDict` that is a subclass of `dict`, modify its `__getitem__` method, and then have `self.r` be a `FancyIndexDict`, not a `dict`.

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know that the slice notation accepted non-int arguments !

Comment: Actually I just tried with other data types, it appears that basically any expression will work, even craziness like `fancy_obj['a':('b', 8)]`

Answer (score 3):

If you know that your `gpos` values will (or can) always be stored in sorted order, then I'd definitely recommend using binary search for this task. You can take advantage of the array syntax and `numpy`'s builtin implementation with [searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
>>> gpos_vals = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
>>> gpos_vals
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ])
>>> lo, hi = gpos_vals.searchsorted([0.22, 0.52])
>>> lo, hi
(3, 6)
>>> gpos_vals[lo:hi]
array([ 0.3,  0.4,  0.5])
```

I think this nicely avoids the issues that you pointed out regarding using floats for dictionary keys, which could be problematic.

You could also combine this answer with Jaime's and make a class that looks for a slice inside a custom `__getitem__`, and then passes the slice parameters to `searchsorted` as in my snippet:

```
class GeneticPositions(object):
    def __init__(self, gpos_values):
        self.gpos_values = np.asarray(gpos_values)

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, slice):
            lo, hi = self.gpos_values.searchsorted(
                [x.start or 0, x.stop or 1])
            return self.gpos_values[lo:hi]
        return self.gpos_values[x]
```

Comment: Nice! You would actually have to check for `None` in the values of `x.start` and `x.stop` before calling `np.searchsorted`: a slice of `[:0.3]` sets `.start` to `None` (and `.stop` to `0.3` as usual).